# Calling a function in react-native gives me an unhandled promise rejection error

Tags: react-native

I am trying to write a function that uses a snippet of code based on what OS the user is on. Here is my function:

```
linearGradient: function() {
  if( Platform.OS == "android" ){
    return (
      <LinearGradient
        start={[0.0, 0]} end={[0.0, 1]}
        locations={[0,1]}
        colors={['rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)']}
        style={styles.linearGradient}>
      </LinearGradient>
    )
  }
  else{
    return (
      <LinearGradient
        start={[0.0, 0.6]} end={[0.0, .94]}
        locations={[0,1]}
        colors={['rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)']}
        style={styles.linearGradient}>
      </LinearGradient>
    )
  }
},
```

Here is where I am calling it:

```
<Image source={{ uri: this.props.thumbnail_img }} style={styles.thumbImg} defaultSource={Images.getImage('black')}>
    {this.linearGradient()}
 </Image>
```

The error I am getting is

> "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection(id:0): null is not an object"

Error being shown on Android Simulator:

[image: error being shown on Android Simulator]

Thanks for your help in advanced!

Comment: what is your componentDIdMount look like